# Reading images without rigid folder structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am  using Tensorflow 2 (Tensorflow 2.2 in particular)

The function below allows us to read in images from folders

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

but it requires us to rigidly structured the folder according to the classes say `cat` and `dog` to be classified as
`data/train/cat` and `data/train/dog`

Say now, we have all the training images in the folder `data/train/` (say `data/train/1.jpg` etc.) and I have train_set `X` and label `y` in the following:

```
X=['1.jpg','2.jpg',...]
y=[0,1,...]
```

where `0` denotes `dog` and `1` denotes `cat` for `y`, and I want to achieve the same effect as the code above (e.g., image aug. like horizontal flipping etc. + with batchsize specified), how should I do that?

**An approach I have tried**:

I use the following code

```
 def preprocess(image):

    img_shape=np.array(image).shape        
    image = tf.cast(np.array(image), tf.float32)
    image = (image / 127.5) - 1
    return image

 image_path=pathlib.Path.joinpath("train", "data")
 class_names=[x.name.lower() for x in image_path.glob('*') if x.is_dir()]
    X=[]
    y=[]


    for path in image_path.glob('**/*'):
        if path.is_file():
            if path.name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')):
                X.append(preprocess(Image.open(path).resize((224,224),resample=Image.BICUBIC)))
                y.append(class_names.index(path.parent.name.lower()))

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1 - train_ratio, stratify=y)
    X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test,
                                                    test_size=test_ratio / (test_ratio + validation_ratio),
                                                    stratify=y_test)


    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size)
    validation_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val)).batch(batch_size)
    test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size)
```

I got out of memory error (as I store all images in `X`), how should I resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

For this I strongly recommend that you use `tf.data.Dataset()`, in order to read and ingest your data.

In fact it is even officially the recommended manner in which the ETL process in TensorFlow (extract,transform,load) should be prepared.

You can have a look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

For example, in your particular case (when you read the documentation it will make more sense), you could use a .map() function in which you retrieve/generate the label 0 or 1 depending on the string in the description of your image.

Or you could also implement it in the way you described above, using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`

In addition, you can use another mapping function for augmentation; you can investigate here the available image preprocessing techniques: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image

From my own work(adapted tutorial from some time ago), I attach here an example:

```
def load_filenames(csv_data, datapath):
    filenames = [os.path.join(datapath, filename) for filename in csv_data['id'].tolist()]
    return filenames


def load_labels(csv_data):
    return csv_data['has_cactus'].tolist()


def parse_fn(filename, label):
    filename = filename.numpy().decode('utf-8')
    print(filename)
    return filename, label


def process_function(filename, label):
    img = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img)
    img = (tf.cast(img, tf.float32) / 127.5) - 1
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (96, 96))
    return img, label
    train_csv = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='data/aerial-cactus-identification/train.csv')
    filenames = load_filenames(csv_data=train_csv, datapath='data/aerial-cactus-identification/train')
    labels = load_labels(csv_data=train_csv)

    train_filenames, val_filenames, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(filenames,
                                                                                labels,
                                                                                train_size=0.9,
                                                                                random_state=42)
    num_train = len(train_filenames)
    num_val = len(val_filenames)
    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (tf.constant(train_filenames), tf.constant(train_labels))
    )

    val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (tf.constant(val_filenames), tf.constant(val_labels))
    )


    train_data = (train_data.map(process_function)
                  .shuffle(buffer_size=num_train)
                  .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                  .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                  )

    val_data = (val_data.map(process_function)
                .shuffle(buffer_size=num_val)
                .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
                )
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited the questions to append with an approach I have tried, which is near to what you have suggested, but I faced a problem which I highlighted in the question, how should I handle that?

Comment: If you get OOM error, then you should decrease the batch_size; in essence this is what happens, not enough video memory.

Comment: You have to use a mapping function, from_tensor_slices().map().batch()

Comment: The OOM is happened in `preprocess` function which I have attached. Reason is that there is too many tensors store in `X`. How should I avoid that?

Comment: The error comes from here:  for path in image_path.glob('**/*'):
        if path.is_file():
            if path.name.lower().endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tiff', '.bmp', '.gif')):
                X.append(preprocess(Image.open(path).resize((224,224),resample=Image.BICUBIC)))
                y.append(class_names.index(path.parent.name.lower()))

Comment: Practically what you do is you load the entire dataset and then split it. You try to load in your memory the entire set of images, which is impossible due to memory constraints. X should contain the path to your images, and y the ground truth. Then you use from_tensor_slices().map().batch()

Comment: But assume `X_train` is path list, `from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train)).map(preprocess)` - I need to load the image in `preprocess`? Again, I still need to read in all images in memory?

Comment: No, because you use .batch() then. TF does this under the hood in order to load it sequentially in batches.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218827/discussion-between-timbus-calin-and-william007).